# [Unity][C#] Is there a command to effect a static variable every X seconds?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I can't convert the static variable into a bool and use 'InvokeRepeating'. Is there any command that could help me out?

Comment: To get the best help, you will need to provide more details.

Comment: What does converting static variable into a bool mean? Can even specify what type is that static variable?

Answer (score 1):

You should create a function that effects that static variable, and use `InvokeRepeating` to *call the function* every X seconds.